# Shared folder empty after opening with NET USE

Tags: batch-file, shared-directory, net-use

I am trying to create a batch file that will map a shared folder on another domain.  After some research, I found the NET USE command to map drives.

```
@echo off
Net Use M: \\IP\Folder\ /persistent:yes /USER:domain\userID PASS
```

This works great for mapping the drive, but when I open it, the folder is empty.  When I remote desktop onto server, I can see that the folder is not empty, and I know the permissions have not changed because I just set them, and no one else has access to change them.  Moreover, if I don't use NET USE and map the drive manually, i get prompted for UserName and Password, and all is well, folder is not empty.

Why is NET USE causing the folder to appear empty?

Answer (score 1):

Likely because the account you used to map the drive does not have read rights on the particular files inside that folder.

Comment: It does.  And I use the same for both the NET USE and the manual mapping.  Same UserID and Pass.

Comment: Then that's just *weird* !

Answer (score -1):

```
@echo off
```

---

```
Start \\Destination_IP\Destination_Folder_Name Password /USER:User_Name 
pause
```

With help of this we can open or copy a shared folder.